# Why is tooltip misplaced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I know that maybe it's something stupid but I can't get my tooltips in the right position, they are always off position

I've looked up here for answers and I tried changing the scripts order, adding others scripts, taking out scripts, and so on, but nothing seems to work.

here is my scripts

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this is how I initialise the tooltips

```
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        container: 'body'
    });
```

and this is the tooltip

```
    <a class="social-button shape-rounded sb-facebook" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook" data-original-title="Facebook">
             <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
```

and this is the current result

[image: wrong position]

***UPDATE***

Adding more space on top as suggested also didn't work

[image]

Comment: how come you use the body as the container? shouldn't the container just be the element hovered?

Comment: @Pete that was a solution found here, but it didn't work I forgot to remove it

Comment: Seems to appear on top if there is enough room above: https://jsfiddle.net/2jdhrpuk/3, if not, then it will; put it below: https://jsfiddle.net/qgmbsoey/

Comment: @Pete it didn't work either

Comment: My point is it works out of the box, so it must be some of the extra styles that you have added, without a [mcve] there is really nothing we can do to help

Comment: @Pete I copied and pasted a bootstrap boton with tooltips and still the same

Comment: @ManuelGonçalves it's possible a Styling from Bootstrap is countering the styling added by jQuery UI. Have you tried with Bootstrap CSS and not the JS?

Comment: @ManuelGonçalves I have added a working snippet below, please have a look at it

Comment: I know it's an old, unsolved mystery at this point, but I came across this thread as I was looking through possible solutions for the exact issue. In my case, the tooltip stays on top of the button, but it's about 100px higher up than where it should be, leaving it almost unnoticeable. Anyone got an update on how this could possibly be avoided? I added the `{container: 'body'}` specification for the function, as instructed by both BS5 and Popper docs, since elements like `.btn-group` are known to cause issues, which in my case seems to be it. Didn't do anything though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `margin-top` to your `div` which wraps your `tooltips` in order to show your `tooltip` at `top`. Below is the working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: center
}

a {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  padding:20px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="border" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a class="border" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="twitter"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a class="border" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="instagram"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a class="border" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="linkedin"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
```